# Algorithm to calculate permutations

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm aware of Heap's algorithm to calculate permutations of a given sequence, but what if I wanted to calculate the permutations of a k-elements subset for a given sequence N?

The solution I'm thinking of this time is a backtracking one, but it would need to generate a new sequence of sub-elements each time deleting one and recursively calling the permutation function. This sounds expensive and I would like to know if there's a better solution

Comment: How big are n and k?  No matter what, you need (n! - k!) answers, so this gets huge really, really quickly.

Comment: You're right and the complexity will be daunting, however allocating space at each recursion is also expensive. I'm just wondering if there's a recursive standard algorithm to generate permutations (N,k)

Comment: @Albert There is an iterative algorithm to generate permutations of a given set. Are you seeking that one?

Comment: @Vesper that might be good. Does it handle k subsets?

Comment: I don't get the question,then. Let's say your sequence `N` is `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`. You apparently want to get a subset of it, say `2 4 8` and then what, get all permutations of that?

Comment: Perhaps I'm using the terms in the wrong way, I want something that can handle permutations of `0,1,2,3,4` with k = 2, i.e. `0,1` `0,2` `0,3`...`3,4` etc.. and since these are permutations `1,2` is different than `2,1`

Comment: use an [algorithm to generate combinations of size k](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n) followed by Heap's algorithm on the result, generate the next size k subset and repeat.

Comment: And you already have the combination generator in place, according to your previous question.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to have a good algorithm combining the twos. @rpattiso make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use an algorithm to generate combinations of size K from the set of N.
   (Pick any from the SO question: [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)).
2. Using the result, apply [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm) to create all permutations of this k-element subset (or another [Algorithm to generate all possible permutations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710713/algorithm-to-generate-all-possible-permutations-of-a-list)).
3. Generate the next subset of size K and repeat (steps 1 and 2) until all subsets of size K have been enumerated.